# Edit existing XFCE theme buttons

Tags: ubuntu, themes, xfce

This is driving me a little nuts;

I'm trying to edit the title bar buttons for a simple theme i created using oomox.
I edited the buttons in `.themes/(Project Name)/xfwm4` but my changes do not seem to stick.

What is the process for editing existing themes for XFCE - specifically, Close, Maximize and Minimize buttons?

Comment: Something isn't right.
I have already edited the XPM files in the xfwm4 folder - The changes did not seem to apply.
I even deleted the xfwm4 folder and there still was no change to the toolbar.
The only folder that seems to apply to this theme is the gtk-3.20 folder. But, I cant find toolbar buttons in there (such as Maximize, Close, Minimize).

Comment: Are you change the theme at Window Manager -> Style instead of Appearance? Maybe you already have a theme with the same name at `/usr/share/themes`. Usually when playing with themes I just switch to another one and back to the one I'm working on.